# Closed form of continued fraction $[0; 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, ...]$

Tags: closed-form, continued-fractions

I was looking at the continued fraction $\frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{2 + \frac{1}{4 + ...}}} = \Large{\mathrm{K}}_{i=0}^\infty {\frac{1}{2^i}}$. Does it have a closed form using well-known functions?

It does not appear in [this](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ContinuedFractionConstants.html) continued fraction constants list.

Comment: Plouffe's Inverse Symbolic Calculator [does not find anything](https://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/cgi-bin/isc/lookup?number=0.691594192421978&lookup_type=smart), but this is no surprise.  Why do you think there might be a closed form?

Comment: @Henry I have no reason to expect one to exist, but I also didn't expect one for $K_{i=1}^\infty \frac1i$ and apparently it does have a closed form.

Comment: Entering the numerical value in Wolfram Alpha does not give a meaningful result either. The closed form for $[0,1,2,3,\cdots]$ uses Bessel-functions , so it is already quite artificial.

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A096641 .